# Read process mem by using read

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, maps

OS: Android 4.3 & 4.4 (root)

Hi all, I am trying to read other processes' memory by calling read(), the most of processes can be read but some can't, for which I list result below:

1. /system/bin/surfaceflinger  return -1
2. /system/bin/surfaceflinger  loss 4096
3. /system/bin/rmt_storage  return -1
4. /system/bin/mediaserver  return -1
5. /system/bin/keystore  return -1
6. /system/bin/qseecomd  return -1
7. /system/bin/hvdcp  return -1
8. system_server  return -1
9. com.android.systemui  return -1
10. com.android.systemui  loss 4096
11. com.android.launcher  return -1
12. com.android.launcher  loss 4096

My flow:
1. call ptrace() to attach
2. call waitpid() to pause
3. fetch address from maps and read from mem

"return -1" means read() return -1. "loss 4096" means the return value of read() was smaller than I had requested, which had 4k bytes loss (for example, I requested 16k, but only 12k was returned, even it did not reach the end).

I guess the reason may be from its special properties, but what's the root cause? 
Thank you! (all addresses were fetched from maps)

Comment: What dev entry are you opening?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean about "dev entry"?